# show that $\frac{\cos(3x)-\sin(3x)}{1-2\sin(2x)}=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

show that $$\frac{\cos 3x -\sin 3x }{1-2\sin 2x}=\sin x + \cos x $$

I tried using compound angle formula first to convert $\sin(3x)$ and $\cos(3x)$ to double and single angles. Then I expanded the double angle but I was not able to simply it any further.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718065/proving-frac-cos3a-sin3a1-2-sin2a-cosa-sina?noredirect=1

Comment: Multiply the denominator by the right-hand side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $$\cos 3x -\sin 3x = (4\cos^3x -3\cos x) -(3\sin x-4\sin^3x)\\  = 4(\sin^3x +\cos^3x) -3(\sin x +\cos x) \\ =(\sin x+\cos x) \left( 4(\sin^2 x +\cos^2 -\sin x \cos x) -3 \right) \\ =(\sin x+\cos x)(1-4\sin x \cos x)$$ while $$1-2\sin2x =1-4\sin x\cos x$$